# i cant use scene builder when i execute my code

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, gluon

I got a problem that I absolutely can't solve on my own because I have just started using JAVA FX.
help me please.
the error

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/DELL/eclipse-workspace/RiadFxProject/bin/application/RiadFxml.fxml

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2714)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2986)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processImport(FXMLLoader.java:2830)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processProcessingInstruction(FXMLLoader.java:2765)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2631)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2555)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3368)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3324)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3292)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3264)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3240)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3233)
    at RiadFxProject/application.Main.start(Main.java:24)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.Avatar
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadTypeForPackage(FXMLLoader.java:3054)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(FXMLLoader.java:3043)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2984)
    ... 20 more
```

main.java

```
package application;
    
import javafx.scene.text.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Group root=new Group();
        try {
        AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("/application/RiadFxml.fxml"));
        Scene scene=new Scene(root,400,400);    
        
        stage.setScene(scene);  
        stage.show();
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
}
```

RiadFxml.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.Avatar?>
<?import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.BottomNavigationButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Arc?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/21" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller=".FXMLController">
   <children>
      <Avatar layoutX="47.0" layoutY="52.0" />
      <BottomNavigationButton layoutX="397.0" layoutY="39.0" />
      <Arc fill="DODGERBLUE" layoutX="126.0" layoutY="200.0" length="270.0" radiusX="100.0" radiusY="100.0" startAngle="45.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" type="ROUND" />
      <Button layoutX="222.0" layoutY="188.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
      <Button layoutX="353.0" layoutY="188.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

I tried some of the solutions previously suggested here. I followed the steps of Pro Code on YouTube, but the problem was not solvedI tried some of the solutions previously suggested here. I followed the steps of Pro Code on YouTube, but the problem was not solved

Comment: I am not sure how `SceneBuilder` factors in here. What is your question?

Comment: I would suggest starting at https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/. I personally like `JavaFX and Netbeans - Non-Modular with Maven`. If you don't use any non-modular dependency, I suggest `JavaFX and Netbeans - Modular with Maven` and `Java with Maven -> FXML JavaFX Maven Archetype`. You can configure `SceneBuilder` with `Netbeans`, and it should open FXML files with no problems.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.Avatar` makes me think you are missing some dependencies(s) or haven't added a dependency to `module-info.java` <- That's assuming that your project is modular.

Comment: [Gluon Charm](https://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/2.0.0/) is a 3rd party framework (I haven't used it and the documentation I linked is old so may be outdated).  Gluon charm is not part of JavaFX, though it does use JavaFX.  [Recent information on using Gluon products](https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_getting_started).  If you wish to use Gluon components, you may consider requesting [support from Gluon](https://gluonhq.com/developers/).  I added the [gluon tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gluon) to your question, in case a Gluon developer chooses to assist you with your question here.

Comment: As you have "just started using JavaFX", I recommend using only standard JavaFX components, e.g. following openjfx.io getting started documentation and, perhaps, the [Makery tutorial](https://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-tutorial/).  After which, you can expand into using third party libraries once you are more familiar with the basic technology.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

If you are new to JavaFX I recommend you to check out this preconfigured non modular project and configure it to your needs:

https://github.com/davidweber411/SimpleJavaFxAppWithoutModules

Just download, extract, start, profit!
Everything ist configured out of the box!

**Alternative**

You can create a running JavaFX project with this project generator:

GitHub link:

https://github.com/davidweber411/JavaFxProjectGenerator

Homepage:

https://wedasoft.com/projects/javafx-project-generator/#

**Note**

I am the author of both.

There is a gradle task for creating am executable fat jar.